# How to remove bulb from ceiling fan fixture

Tags: ceiling-fan

I can't figure out how to get into the light fixture on this fan. There don't appear to be any screws or tabs. I tried pulling it down gently. I also tried twisting it gently. It is possible that it twists or pulls down, but I don't want to damage the fan by applying too much pressure. How do I change the bulb on this fan?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be little metal pressure tabs holding in place, it's just a matter of applying a little more downward force. How? Pry it around the edges, gently and carefully, with a screw driver or dinner knife, don't mar it. Or use tape like in the picture below. More information in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXHylBQzrIs)

[image]